# Adding a space between a number with setText

Tags: android

Sorry for such a simple question, but how would you put a space between a random number that is being generated and then sent to setText?

It now displays ########, but I want it to display as #### ####

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_randnumber);
text.setText(String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 100000000)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_randnumber);
String random = String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 100000000));
String one = random.substring(0, 4);
String two = random.substring(4, 8);
text.setText(one + " " + two);
```

This must work.

Comment: One thing to be wary of though: If you are going to perform this many times, for example in a loop, you might want to look into a more optimized solution as this to avoid the excessive creation of strings (here four different string instances are used for one modification).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably one of those questions that has a million correct answers, here's one way to do it:

```
String string = String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 100000000));
string = new StringBuilder(string).insert(4, ' ').toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is a convenience method for accessing formatter functionality. The first parameter is a 'format string' that support several flags.

The flag for grouping separators for large numbers is `,` so you can write:

```
text.setText(String.format("%,d", (int)(Math.random() * 100000000)))
```

For all available flags see [`Formatter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)

In this way will be used the Locale grouping (thousand) separator. If you want to customize this separator (with a blank space for example) you need to do the following:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###", dfs);
text.setText(df.format(Math.random() * 100000000));
```

Comment: Works - text.setText(String.format("%,d", (int)(Math.random() * 100000000)))

Answer (score 0):

```
   int i=(int)Math.random() * 100000000 ;
   int rem= i%10000;
   int i=i/10000;
   text.setText(String.valueOf(i+" " +rem));
```